# Check id and class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

I've tried to check my `id` with jQuery, and I'm wondering why it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

```
<td class="food" id="butter">
    butter
</td>
<td class="food" id="milk">
    milk
</td>
```

```js
$(function(){
    if ($('.food').attr('id') == "butter"){
        $('.food').css({ color: 'red' });
    } else { 
        $('.food').css({ color: 'blue' });
    }
});
```

It shows all red. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can query the id with $('#id') ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly there are multiple `.food` elements, so you need to loop using `each()`, and then within that loop you need to use `this` to reference only the current element. Try this:

```
$('.food').each(function() {
    if (this.id == "butter"){
        $(this).css({ color: 'red' });
    } else { 
        $(this).css({ color: 'blue' });
    }
});
```

You can then shorten this even further with the use of a ternary:

```
$('.food').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', this.id == 'butter' ? 'red' : 'blue');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/d2hf2ac3/)

Answer (score 2):

Or without `.each()`:

```
$(".food").css({color: 'blue'}).filter("#butter").css({color: 'red'});
```

Comment: @GiantApe if the answer was helpful you should consider to Accept Answers. Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ... it's a way to say "thanks" here on StackOverflow. You already asked 13 questions and accepted none. Also, read [tour]. It's all there if you missed it!